# Python: Import graphic into to Excel and export whole sheet as EPS

Tags: python, excel, openoffice.org, xlwt

For a current project I need advanced access to Excel via Python.
I found the xlwt project on http://www.python-excel.org/ that allows me to
create Excel files and store data into the cells. That's fine.

Unfortunately I need also the following features:

- Import a external graphic file (EPS)
- Export a whole spreadsheet as EPS

Any one who knows how to fix this?
Workaround using OpenOffice is also OK (even better, we all love free software).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll tackle your requirements one at a time:

**Import an external graphic file in EPS format**

[xlwt](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt) will allow you to import images into your spreadsheet, but only in BMP format.  First you will have to rasterise your EPS file into BMP format, then do:

```
from xlwt import *

w = Workbook() 
ws = w.add_sheet('Image')
ws.insert_bitmap('python.bmp', 2, 2)

w.save('image.xls')
```

[taken from [this](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlwt/trunk/xlwt/examples/image.py) example in the source]

**Export a whole spreadsheet as EPS**

What you are describing requires Excel itself (or OpenOffice / equivalent) - as it is a rendering operation.  The python-excel library you are using is for manipulating the Excel file format, not for rendering it.